# How to package dependencies in a Grails 3 plugin using gradle?

Tags: java, grails, gradle, plugins, build-dependencies

I'm having difficulty generating a Grails 3.2.7 plugin with its dependencies.

This works and creates a JAR with all dependencies:

```
gradle clean build
```

..but not this; the JAR has no dependencies, just plugin project files:

```
gradle publishToMavenLocal
```

My gradle file, I know there's something missing, and based on the docs it's my understand there's no native feature to do this.

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        grailsVersion = project.grailsVersion
    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:$grailsVersion"
        classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:3.0.1"
    }
}

plugins {
    id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "0.5.2.RELEASE"
    id "com.jfrog.bintray" version "1.2"
}

version "3.1-SNAPSHOT"
group "mygroup"


apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: "org.springframework.boot"
apply plugin: "com.jfrog.artifactory"
apply plugin: "org.grails.grails-plugin"
apply plugin: "org.grails.grails-gsp"
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'


ext {
    grailsVersion = project.grailsVersion
    gradleWrapperVersion = project.gradleWrapperVersion
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

idea {
    module {
        downloadSources = true
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.grails:grails-bom:$grailsVersion"
    }
    applyMavenExclusions false
}

dependencies {
    provided 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging'
    provided "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    provided "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
    provided "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"

    provided "org.grails:grails-web-boot"
    provided "org.grails:grails-dependencies"
    provided 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0'

    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-testing"
    testCompile "com.fiftyonred:mock-jedis:0.4.0"

    console "org.grails:grails-console"
    compile "redis.clients:jedis:2.5.2"
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = gradleWrapperVersion
}


artifactory {
    contextUrl = 'http://myrepo/'

}

task sourceJar(type: Jar) {
    from sourceSets.main.allJava
}

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue stems from the publishing section:

When I change this to:

```
task jarWithPlainPom(type: Jar) {
    from sourceSets.main.output
    from configurations.runtime
}

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {

            artifact jarWithPlainPom
        }
    }
}
```

It includes most of the needed dependencies, however the POM is not updated and the project fails when importing the plugin.